# Is a ruler an example of metric spaces?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was reading metric spaces and tried to think about some real life example of metric spaces. I think it will be a metric space.  Am I correct?

Comment: You will need to define a metric on the ruler to make it a metric spaces.

Answer (score 2):

That will depend a bit on what you mean by "ruler". You have to use a mathematic definition of such object.

But let's assume that you by a ruler means a line segment accompanied with a scale, that is a linear assignment of "length markings" ranging from 0 up to some maximal value. And then define the distance between two point as the absolute difference in these markings.

Then yes it's a metric space, it's isomorph to the real line segment from 0 to the maximal value which in turn is a metric space.

Comment: What exactly is distance in a metric space? It depends on the way I define it right? I can make the distance between two points as (x2-x1)^(1/2)and then if all the axioms of metric space holds a ruler becomes a metric space..

Comment: @GuriaSona Yes, I just made a reasonable assumption on what metric you had in mind. Btw you would need to take the absolute value of $x_2 - x_1$ in order to be able to always take the square root (otherwise that seem to work).

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that for most humans, imagining "spaces" that are *not* metric spaces is more difficult! Our daily lives are littered with metric spaces. Sometimes you think about how many blocks you need to walk, sometimes you talk about how many hours you need to drive. In American Football you only really care about the single dimension of yardage, despite having a two dimensional football field. A great deal of the definitions in topology have direct inspiration from metric spaces and are just attempts at generalizing this idea.

Comment: What do you think is a real life example which is not a metric space ?Almost everything is a metric space? Can you suggest me some good books on metric spaces.

Comment: I'll boldly claim that there are no real life examples of topological spaces that are not metric spaces. For several examples of non-metrizeable spaces, see https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=~metrizable. The only one that is close to "real life", in my option (and it is just that, an opinion) is the Long Line. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology).